# Refreshing Android Tabs without Intent

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost

Please how can I refresh the content of Tab 2 (tag 2,Live blog) without adding intent.

TabHost th = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost1);
        th.setup();

```
     TabHost.TabSpec spec = th.newTabSpec("tag1")
     .setIndicator("Testimonies", getResources()
      .getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_testimonies_tab))
        .setContent(R.id.tab1);
           th.addTab(spec);


     spec = th.newTabSpec("tag2")
     .setIndicator("Live Blog", getResources()
     .getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_liveblog_tab))
      .setContent(R.id.tab2);
        th.addTab(spec);


        spec = th.newTabSpec("tag3")
        .setIndicator("Streaming Settings", getResources()
        .getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_streamingsetting_tab))
        .setContent(R.id.tab3);
          th.addTab(spec);

          th.setCurrentTab(1);

          th.getCurrentView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: I mean i want to refresh my tabs, but i don't  have intent in the tabs, is this possible and how can this be done if its possble.

Comment: TabHost refresh? Why? Anything special. Include more detail for more clarification.

Comment: Thanks for responding guys, but i mean, refreshing my android Tabs, in the absence of an intent in the tabs.

Comment: Put in some code or screen shots, so that its clear what you need.

Comment: or just, like, refresh with a refresh button (so 1999)

Comment: Thank for responding njzk2, no refreshing without a refresh button. Is this possible without using intent and if its possible how can it be done, i was following a tutorial online which has worked, but i just need to refresh the content of the second tab. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We "see" each other again, @meduteniopeyemi ! I worked hard trying to solve the issue you are talking about. And the aproach that I used to do it was:

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

                    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                            //YOUR CODE checking if "tabId" is the tab you want to REFRESH
                    }
            });
```

It worked so far for me. It just allows you to do any refreshing without problems.

Comment: @ carlos, thank you so much, you have been of great help, at this point can i have your email address, you will be of great help to me in the future

Comment: Sure, no problem! You have it in my profile's page. It was a pleasure to help you :)

Comment: i have checked, its not on your page,

Comment: I think we are already in touch through Google+ and Linkedin. I wouldn't dare to share my email here... ;)